# Is there a syntactically legal expression that has 2 consecutive identifiers separated only by white space in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax

That might not be the best way to phrase it, but I'm considering writing a tool that converts identifiers separated by spaces in my code to camel case.  A quick example:

```
var zoo animals = GetZooAnimals(); // i can't help but type this
var zooAnimals = GetZooAnimals(); // i want it to rewrite it like this
```

I was wondering if writing a tool like this would run into any ambiguities assuming it ignores all keywords.  The only reason I can think of is if there is a syntactically valid expression with 2 identifiers only separated by white space.

Looking through the [grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(v=vs.71).aspx) I could not immediately find a place that allows it, but perhaps someone else would know better.

On a side note, I realize this is not a practical solution to a real problem a lot of people have, but just something I do all the time and wanted to take a stab at fixing with tools instead of forcing myself to always write camel case.

Comment: `Myclass myVariable;` is a valid sequence of two identifiers separated by space.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight good call.  If you want to add it as an answer, you'll get the check.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: in the case of declaration, the first "identifier" or keyword is seen as the "type-identifier" and the next as the "real identifier".

Comment: @CommuSoft That's correct. However, if the tool the OP wants to write is to camel-case both identifiers, a declaration like `Zoo animal my animal;` would become ambiguous.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: not necessarily. Say you have modified the source code such that every line matches with one statement. Then you could perform `(\w*)?(\s+\w+)+` and combine all matches of the second group for a declaration statement. Since the context-free grammar exists. It can be extremely hard to slightly modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell whether a space-separated sequence of identifiers represents a single variable or not without doing full semantic analysis. For example

```
Myclass myVariable;
```

is a pair of space-separated identifiers which are perfectly valid. This would cause an ambiguity if you want to camel-case both type names and variable names.

Answer (score 2):

If one enters:

```
csharp> var i j = 3;
(1,7): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `j', expecting `,', `;', or `='
```

in the `csharp` interactive shell, one gets an error generated by the parser (a (LA)LR parser does bookkeeping what to expect next). Such parser works *left-to-right* so it doesn't know which characters to come next. It simply knows that the next characters are one of the list shown above.

So that means that there is probably no way to - at least declare a variable - with spaces.

Furthermore based on [this context-free grammar](http://public.beuth-hochschule.de/oo-plug/Cis/txt/Syntax.html) for C# there doesn't seem to be a case where one can place two identifiers next to each other. It is for instance possible that a *primary expressions* is an identifier, but there is no situation where a *primary expression* is placed next to an *identifier* (or with an optional part in between).

As @dasblinkenlight says, you can indeed see the rule ["local-variable-declaration"](http://public.beuth-hochschule.de/oo-plug/Cis/txt/Syntax.html#local-variable-declaration):

```
type variable-declarator
```

with `type` that can be evaluated to an identifier and variable-declarator starting with an identifier. You can however know that the type is the first identifier (or the `var` keyword). Some kind of rewrite rule is thus:

```
(\w+)(\s+\w+)+ -> \1 concat(\2)
```

where you need to combine (`concat`) the identifiers of the second group. In case of an assignment.

Comment: The goal here is to write a tool for my IDE that notices I've done this and to just convert it to camel case immediately for me.  Since I normally do it when declaring a variable, this should be enough to warrant it being a viable thing.